# update based on selected checkboxes is not working correctly

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table posts that has two columns "share_inst", "share_tw" as tinyints and by default they are "0".

I have a form that allows a admin of the post to select if we wants that a post can be shared in all sites or just one or none. But its not working.

When I select the sites and click in "Update" I get the error:

```
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'share_inst' cannot be null (SQL: update `posts` set `share_inst` = , `share_tw` =  where `id` = 1)
```

Also in the form the checkboxes are not appearing checked if in database the columns "share_inst" and "share_tw" and "1".

Do you know where is the error?

**Form**:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('posts.share.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])"}}>
  {{csrf_field()}}
  {{ method_field('PATCH') }}

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName">
      Select which sites the post can be shared</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="share_tw" id="share_tw" value="share_tw"
             {{ $post->share_tw == 0 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
        Twiiter
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="share_inst" id="share_inst" value="share_inst"
             {{ $post->share_inst == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
        Instagram
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

**Update method:**

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->share_tw = $request->share_tw;
        $post->share_ins = $request->share_ins;
        $post->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

**Edit method**

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);

        return view('posts.share.edit')->with('post', $post);
    }
```

**Routes:**

```
// update shared
Route::get('post/edit/{id}/share',    [ 'uses' => 'ShareController@edit', 'as'=>'posts.share.edit']);
Route::post('post/update/{id}/share', [ 'uses' => 'ShareController@update', 'as'=>'posts.share.update']);
```

Comment: why do you have  the same code - `{{ $post->share_tw == 0 ? 'checked' : '' }} {{ $post->share_tw == 0 ? 'checked' : '' }}"?

Comment: Thanks, i will update the question to remove that.

Comment: add the result of `dd($request->all());` when both checkbox are selected.

Comment: The result is: "share_tw" => "share_tw" "share_inst" => "share_inst".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, if a checkbox *is not* ticked, it is not usually included in the request. When a checkbox *is* ticked, its value is included in the request.

Try updating your `update` method to something like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $post->share_tw = $request->input('share_tw', 0);
    $post->share_ins = $request->input('share_ins', 0);
    $post->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And set the value of each of your checkboxes to be `1` in your view:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="share_tw" id="share_tw" value="1"{!! $post->share_tw == 1 ? ' checked' : '' !!}>
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="share_inst" id="share_inst" value="1"{!! $post->share_inst == 1 ? ' checked' : '' !!}>
```

So what happens here is that when you submit the form, you're actually submitting the value `1` against each of your two checkboxes, if they're ticked. If they're not ticked, nothing is passed through in the request, but by using the `input` method and specifying a second parameter as a default value, you're saying that if there's no value for your checkbox, use `0`. This way you'll either end up setting the value to a `1` or a `0`.

If you'd rather not use the `input` method, and you would prefer to access the value from the request as if it were a property, you could do this instead to get the same result:

```
$post->share_tw = $request->share_tw ?: 0;
$post->share_ins = $request->share_ins ?: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked checkboxes are **not submitted**, you need to change your update code to something like :

```
    $post->share_tw = !is_null($request->share_tw);
    $post->share_ins = !is_null($request->share_ins);
```

This will convert a checked checkbox to a boolean value to make sure your query get executed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked check boxes are not submitted, So you need to check the existence of input

```
$post->share_tw = isset($request->share_tw) ? 1 : 0;
$post->share_ins = isset($request->share_ins) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: it apperas the same error even with that code before $post->share_tw= $request->share_tw...

Comment: Thanks, but it still appears the sql integrity error.

Comment: Before  $post->share_tw= $request->share_tw; $post->share_inst = $request->share_inst; $post->save();

Comment: This columns in the migration of posts have default(false) like: $table->boolean('share_tw')->default(false);

Comment: public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        
        $post->share_tw = isset($request->share_tw) ? 1 : 0;
        $post->share_ins = isset($request->share_ins) ? 1 : 0;
        
        $post->share_tw = $request->share_tw;
        $post->share_ins = $request->share_ins;
        $post->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }

Comment: @AdamK oho.. you are doing it wrong!!remove these lines..`$post->share_tw = $request->share_tw; 
$post->share_ins = $request->share_ins; `

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! Now dont appears any error but in database is always "0" after select both checkboxes and click in "update" button.